Lorry or truck driver. He has been rained on his entire life. He is unaware he is a rain god. Clouds love him
Short story in a comic about insectoid aliens approaching Earth in an invasion armada. They attack lights that turn-out to be a truck's windshield
This question reminded me of a book a read in the 90s or 0Os. It was hardback with a dark dustcover.
The lorry driver had been rained on his entire life. The rain clouds follow above him everywhere he drives.
He is completely unaware that he is a rain god. All the rainclouds know is that they love him and always want to be with him. The book was humourous.

This is Douglas Adams' So Long, and Thanks for all the Fish.  Lorry driver Rob McKenna is, though he doesn't know it, a god of rain:

And as he drove on, the rainclouds dragged down the sky after him, for, though he did not know it, Rob McKenna was a Rain God. All he knew was that his working days were miserable and he had a succession of lousy holidays. All the clouds knew was that they loved him and wanted to be near him, to cherish him, and to water him.

Rob has categorized more than two hundred types of rain:

Rob McKenna had two hundred and thirty-one different types of rain entered in his little book, and he didn’t like any of them.
[...]
Since he had left Denmark the previous afternoon, he had been through types 33 (light pricking drizzle which made the roads slippery), 39 (heavy spotting), 47 to 51 (vertical light drizzle through to sharply slanting light to moderate drizzle freshening), 87 and 88 (two finely distinguished varieties of vertical torrential downpour), 100 (post-downpour squalling, cold), all the sea-storm types between 192 and 213 at once, 123, 124, 126, 127 (mild and intermediate cold gusting, regular and syncopated cab-drumming), 11 (breezy droplets), and now his least favorite of all, 17.
Rain type 17 was a dirty blatter battering against his windshield so hard that it didn’t make much odds whether he had his wipers on or off.

And he describes his diary, how no matter where he's gone it has rained:

"I have a book," he went on, "I have a book. A diary. Kept it for fifteen years. Shows every single place I've ever been. Every day. And also what the weather was like. And it was uniformly," he snarled, "'orrible. All over England, Scotland, Wales I been. All round the Continent, Italy, Germany, back and forth to Denmark, been to Yugoslavia. It's all marked in and charted. Even when I went to visit my brother," he added, "in Seattle."

The hardcover had a dark cover:


Yeah, this is it. You got it so quick the system will not let me accept it yet
